# Failed to Compile react project - You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders

Tags: javascript, reactjs

File was processed with these loaders:

- ../node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/loader/index.js
- ../node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
  You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
  |       fontSize: 61.2
  |     }

> })), dialogTitle?.length ? /*#**PURE***/React.createElement(DialogTitle, {
> |     id: "alert-dialog-title",
> |     textAlign: "center"

To compile the whole react code and run successfully